# How to build 2 versions of the same project using maven

Tags: java, android, maven, maven-3, maven-release-plugin

I have a android project that is customised for customers. So I have build 2 apk's
The first is the common apk , which is the actual application that cannot start by itself, the second apk is client specific. This calls the first one passing the client name as the parameter so that the general apk can work according the client name passed.

This is turning out to be inefficient as the client number keeps growing. So I want to have a single apk, but build separately for different customers. I don't want to duplicate the project for each customer separately. How can we do this using maven?

From maven [blogs](http://blog.sonatype.com/2010/01/how-to-create-two-jars-from-one-project-and-why-you-shouldnt/#.UvyYa0KSxl8),they don't recommend this. Any help much appreciated

Comment: Could you make use of [Maven profiles](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-profiles.html)? You could split out customer specific config into different profiles and then invoke a particular profile when you build: `mvn package -P customerX`.

Comment: I would suggest to make two executions for the plugin to get as a result with a single build.

Comment: Yes, I am doing that. But how do I use commom properties of release profile for all the cutomers. Say I want to use release profile for customer ABC. How do we do such complex builds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a project for each client which only contains resources like names. Bundle your main application as source apk with the following plugin:
[ApkSourcesDependency](http://code.google.com/p/maven-android-plugin/wiki/ApkSourcesDependency)

And finally use your main Application as dependency in your client pom. This can be generalized with a parent pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>enter.groupid.here</groupId>
    <artifactId>myapp-common-stuff</artifactId>
    <type>apksources</type>
</dependency>
```

After that just build every client project